# Unsure how this piece of code is doing what it does… .getDescribe()

Tags: java, salesforce, apex

I'm relatively new to Apex and Java.

Could someone possibly explain this snippet of code?

```
Map<String, SObjectField> m = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (String name : m.keySet()) {
    DescribeFieldResult r = m.get(name).getDescribe();
    System.debug(r);
}
```

I know it's getting the Describe information for each field on the Opportunity object, but could someone explain, line by line, how it's doing it?

Cheers!

Comment: Is this Java or Apex? They have a similar syntax, but they are distinct languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about as basic as it gets when you need to enumerate a map:

- Line 1 gets the map, and stores it in variable `m`
- Line 2 iterates over the keys of the map `m`, using `name` variable for the value of the key in this iteration
- Line 3 gets the item from the map `m` using `name` for the key, and calls `getDescribe`
- Line 4 passes the result to `System.debug`
- Line 5 closes the loop

However, this is not the best way of iterating the values, though: a simpler approach would be as follows:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> m = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (SObjectField val : m.values()) {
    System.debug(val.getDescribe());
}
```

For completeness, if you would like to iterate both keys and values, iterate `entrySet`, like this:

```
Map<String, SObjectField> m = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (Map.Entry<String,SObjectField> e : m.entrySet()) {
    // e.getKey() produces the key
    // e.getValue() produces its associated value
}
```

Iterating keys and then retrieving the values in a separate call to `get` is inefficient.

Comment: Really appreciate the answer dasblinkenlight, but I'm getting an error with m.valueSet(). 

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [MAP<String,Schema.SObjectField>].valueSet()`

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @Daft Because I typed a wrong name :) It should be `values()`, not `valueSet()`.

Comment: If this is Apex rather than Java then the Salesforce Map doesn't have the entrySet() method. [Salesforce Map Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_methods)